# Mysql join two tables issue

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have two tables in my database. Am struggling to join those tables to get data.

My game table look like this way

[image]

My fb_request table look like this way 
[image]

My aim is to get game information from game table like venue, game_date, logo for user_id = 17. I have set game_selected as foreign key in my fb_requests table. Please help me to write a join query for these two tables. Thank in advance. Now am using separate select query to fetch data

Comment: What is the current query you're using?

Comment: First am selecting game_selected from fb_request table 
$sql = "select DISTINCT(game_selected) FROM fb_requests where user_id='".$user_id."'";

Then again fetching venue,game_date,logo form game table based on first select querys result. I know its not the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select g.venue,g.game_date,g.logo,fb.game_selected as game_id,fb.accept_status,fb.request_id 
 from fb_request fb 
 left join game g on (fb.game_selected=g.id)
 where fb.user_id=17;
```

Comment: if you want result for only the game which user has accepted, then append  `accept_status=1` in `where` clause, your where statement should be like this , `where fb.user_id=17 and accept_status=1`;

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, now am getting 4 rows based on game_selected. How can i get distinct values for game_selected ?

Comment: pass 2nd statement in `where` clause like `where fb.user_id=17 and accept_status=1;` or use `group by fb.game_selected` after `where` statement

Answer (score 1):

Try this,please check your table name

```
Select tbl1.venue,tbl1.game_date,tbl1.logo tbl_game tbl1
    inner join fb_request tbl2 on tbl1.id = tbl2.id
    where tbl2.user_id = 17
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
venue, game_date, logo 
FROM game_table JOIN fb_request_table 
ON (id = game_selected) 
WHERE user_id = $user_id 
GROUP BY user_id, game_selected
```

The `GROUP BY` makes sure you get unique combination of `user_id` and `game_selected` values

I suggest you go through [**Visual Representation of JOINS**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins) to get an idea of how `JOINS` work.